# Finding Substring Using REGEX_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, regex, database, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to extract the sub-string of **Twitter and Fortnite**, **Facebook and Words with Friends**, & **Expedia and Notion** from the strings below. These are just examples and the common pattern amongst all of them is *"AppNames";s:xx:"* with *xx* being a different number for each string. I'm having a difficult time accounting for the different numbers. Here is my current REGEX_SUBSTR query that doesn't take into account the varying numerical value in *s:xx*

```
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(FORM_FIELDS, '"AppNames";s:17:\"([^\"]+)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Just to reiterate, the above query will output **Twitter and Fortnite**, which is correct for the first string but I have many other strings that are similar but have a different numerical patterns such as...

- "AppNames";s:35
- "AppNames";s:50
- "AppNames";s:44

STRINGS

> ```
> s:25:"Social/Games";s:14:"AppNames";s:17:"Twitter and Fortnite";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}
> s:25:"Social/Games";s:14:"AppNames";s:35:"Facebook and Words with Friends";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}
> s:15:"Travel/Productivity";s:19:"AppNames";s:50:"Expedia and Notion";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data(FORM_FIELDS) as (
    SELECT * from values
    ('s:25:"Social/Games";s:14:"AppNames";s:17:"Twitter and Fortnite";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}'),
    ('s:25:"Social/Games";s:14:"AppNames";s:35:"Facebook and Words with Friends";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}'),
    ('s:15:"Travel/Productivity";s:19:"AppNames";s:50:"Expedia and Notion";s:12:"Audience";s:20;}')
)
select 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(FORM_FIELDS, '"AppNames";s:[0-9]+:\"([^\"]+)', 1, 1, 'e') as new
    ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(FORM_FIELDS, '"AppNames";s:17:\"([^\"]+)', 1, 1, 'e') as old
from data;
```

gives:

| NEW | OLD |
| --- | --- |
| Twitter and Fortnite | Twitter and Fortnite |
| Facebook and Words with Friends | null |
| Expedia and Notion | null |

so `[0-9]+` will match 1+ digits, you can also use `\\d+` but if you only want 2 `\\d{2}` will force that.